# How to disable scaling div on smartphone

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

I have problem with navbar on my html page. When I open my site on smartphone and try to scale something, navbar (fixed to top) goes to scale too and my css exploades :)
How can I make navbar does not scale on mobile devices?

Comment: Would be helpful if you included your current html!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. You can use

```
.navbar {
  max-width: 940px;
  min-width: 940px;
}
```

Or mediaqueries

```
@media all and (max-width: 940px) {
.navbar{width:940px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You configure viewport and other settings in the meta which should be in the  section of the **HTML** document

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,
maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">`

[Viewport Meta Tag on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

2. You build your **stylesheet** => css with percentages. e.g.: **div** with `height: 100%; width: 100%`.